# C# login program, with external Sql Server

Tags: c#, mysql

How are you doing? So where I'm gonna start: my problem is that I have created a program with login to the external Sql Server but when I try to connect I get a message that username or password are wrong.

The C# code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace LBImqP
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(@"Data Source=localhost;port=3306;Initial Catalog=lbimqp;User ID=root;password='server1234'");
        int i;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            i = 0;
            con.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO `login` VALUES (`username`, `password`)";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            i = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows.Count.ToString());

            if (i == 0)
            {
                wrong.Text = "Username or password is wrong!";
            }
            else
            {
                this.Hide();
                mainscreen ms = new mainscreen();
                ms.Show();
            }
            con.Close();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

**The user is created in the mysql database.
here is a picture:**
[Mysql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqcNL.png)

And every time when I need to login system says that the username or the password are wrong and I have no idea why. I hope someone can help me. Thanks. :)

Comment: INSERT doesn't return any rows, so `dt.Rows.Count` is zero, which is the value you're getting. Your code is wrong. `if (i  == 0)` will always be true on an INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE. And INSERTing won't fail for an *invalid username or password* unless you have a trigger that does some validation of password requirements or a UNIQUE constraint or index.

Comment: I need SELECT right?

Comment: `SELECT` would query whether a user already exists. `INSERT` creates a new row. Which one you need would depend on what you're doing. Find a basic SQL tutorial, and learn how to use SQL. If you're trying to log in, then you should stop trying to INSERT and use SELECT. Your code is not trying to log in, it's adding a new user.